# MYSQL check if a table value is contained in a passed string

Tags: mysql

So basically im stuck in this problem.
Let's say my string is this "IIS Blaise Pascal" and inside my table in mysql I have a field that contains "Blaise Pascal" how can i return that field with a query?

I have tried with LIKE %string% but it doesn't work

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think you want:

```
SELECT *
FROM table t
WHERE "IIS Blaise Pascal" LIKE CONCAT('%', t.field, '%')
;
```

Answer (score 0):

I think this query can help you:

```
select
case 
  when field1 like '%Pascal%' then 'field1'
  when field2 like '%Pascal%' then 'field2'
  when field3 like '%Pascal%' then 'field3'
end as fieldname
from table
where 
  field1 like '%Pascal%' or
  field2 like '%Pascal%' or
  field3 like '%Pascal%'
```